# My onResume depends on `onViewCreated`. How can I redesign it?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have a fragment and `onViewCreated` an AsyncTask is started that loads some data in the background and in `onPostExecute` it loads the data to an `ArrayAdapter` to be displayed to a list in the UI.
Now `onResume` I need to load some other data that needs to be loaded in a background thread. So I can use start an AsyncTask for that.
This second background task loads some other data from another data source.

**Problem:** Once these data are loaded and before finishing process I need to do access the data loaded in the `ArrayAdapter` from the `AsyncTask` of `onViewCreated`.
Taking into account that:
1) I should not access the `ArrayAdapter` from a non-UI thread and
2) I can't be sure that the `AsyncTask` of `onViewCreated` has already been finished (I recently was informed that AsyncTasks are actually run one after the other)
How can I fix my design so that this works?
Please note that the data loaded `onViewCreated` are much much more than the data loaded `onResume` so preferably I would not want to reload them on each resume

Comment: Why can't you check the status of the `AsyncTask`? `myasync.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED`

Comment: @JuanCortes:Thank you. That would solve issue (2) I think. But what about issue (1)?

Comment: `onPostExecute` and `onPreExecute` are run on the UI thread as far as I know http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)

Comment: @JuanCortes:Yes but I need access to the data loaded from task 1 from the `doInBackground`

Comment: In case you want to access it before `onPostExecute` use `runOnUiThread` and wrap your code inside a runnable, or use `onProgressUpdate` which also runs on the UI thread

Comment: The issue is that I need to run background code that depends on the data loaded to the `ArrayAdapter` and might need to update the `ArrayAdapter` as a consequence but I don't intent to update the UI at this point in the second task

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109984/discussion-between-juan-cortes-and-jim).

Comment: What type of task do you have(cpu/io bound)?

Comment: @MaximG:Network call

Answer (score 0):

You can check the status of your `AsyncTask` with a call to `.getStatus()` and see if it's ie finished (`AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED`). As for accessing the adapter from inside the asyncTask, you need to use `onProgressUpdate`, which is triggered on every update of the task, or in case you don't update the progress, it can be wrapped inside a `Runnable` like so:

```
//Inside doInBackground
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //Your logic
    }
});
```

The difference is that if your code is something like downloading an image, or a file, that will be run inside a loop, reading n bytes everytime. You can call `publishProgress(Progress...)` to trigger the `onProgressUpdate` method and show feedback to the user, as in 50% downloaded.

Comment: But if AsyncTasks run one after the other how can the `getStatus` work unless one is always scheduled after the other